# Referencing properties of object constructor outside view model in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So, I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this question as it's sort of two in one. I'm having a weird issue where I have an object constructor to create new 'projects' from an HTML form which are then pushed into an observableArray when the form is submitted. Everything works fine but to reference the related observables I have to use 'value: Project.title' or 'value: Project.whatever'. I haven't seen 'value: NameOfConstructor.property' used in any of the examples I've seen. I assume this works this way because the constructor is outside of my view model.

My question is this: Is there a better way to assign the value of a property in a constructor that is not in my view model? In other words, is there a better or more correct way than 'Project.title', ect?
I ask partially because one thing in my code doesn't work currently; the knockout enable property doesn't work on my "New Project" button, it stays disabled even if there is something written in the 'title' input box. I have the feeling it's because it's written as data-bind='enable: Project.title' but I can't figure how else to write it.

I've included a jsfiddle for reference though it obviously isn't working because of external dependencies.
https://jsfiddle.net/bmLh0vf1/1/

My HTML:

```
<form id='addBox' action='#' method='post'>
    <label for='pTitle'> Title: </label>
    <input id='pTitle' data-bind='value: Project.title' />
    <br/>
    <label for='pPriority'> Priority </label>
    <select id='pPriority' data-bind='options: priorityOptions, value: Project.priority'></select>
    <br/>
    <button data-bind='enable: Project.title, click: newProject'>New Project</button>
  </form>
```

And my Javascript:

```
function Project(title, priority) {
  this.title = ko.observable(title);
  this.priority = ko.observable(priority);
};


function ProjectViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.priorityOptions = ko.observableArray(['High', 'Medium', 'Low'])
  this.projectList = ko.observableArray([
    new Project('Create App', 'High')
  ]);
  this.newProject = function() {
    var np = new Project(Project.title, Project.priority);
    self.projectList.push(new Project(Project.title, Project.priority));
    console.log(self.projectList().length);
    if (self.projectList().length > 1) {
      console.log(self.projectList()[1].title());
    };
  }
};

var viewModel = new ProjectViewModel();
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

Lastly, I apologize if I've missed any posting conventions or if my code is especially bad. I'm very new and still teaching myself.

Comment: Unrelated, but you can avoid all that tedious linking form controls with labels via `for`/`id` by putting the form control *in* the label.

Comment: Haha, that would have saved me some time. It's good to know! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is setting `title` and `priority` properties on the object created by `new Project`, but then later you're expecting to see those properties on `Project` itself. It doesn't have them; `Project` is the function, not the object created by `new Project`. So `Project.title` and `Project.priority` will give you `undefined` (and not an observable, and so not useful targets for the `value` binding).

Instead, have an "editing" `Project` *instance* that you use, binding the `value` of the inputs to the editing' instances `title` and `priority`, and then in `newProject` grab that instance and replace it with a new, fresh one.

Roughly speaking, in `ProjectViewModel`'s constructor:

```
this.editing = ko.observable(new Project());
```

Update `Project` to default `title` and `priority`:

```
function Project(title, priority) {
  this.title = ko.observable(title || "");
  this.priority = ko.observable(priority || "Medium");
}
```

And in the bindings:

```
<input id='pTitle' data-bind='value: editing().title' />
<select id='pPriority' data-bind='options: priorityOptions, value: editing().priority'></select>
```

And in `newProject`:

```
var np = this.editing();
this.editing(new Project());
```

Then use `np` (instead of another `new Project`) when adding to the array.

Here's a simplified example:

```js
function Project(title, priority) {
  this.title = ko.observable(title || "");
  this.priority = ko.observable(priority || "Medium");
}


function ProjectViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.priorityOptions = ko.observableArray(["High", "Medium", "Low"]);
  this.projects = ko.observableArray();
  this.editing = ko.observable(new Project());
  this.addProject = function() {
    this.projects.push(this.editing());
    this.editing(new Project());
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ProjectViewModel(), document.body);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Title:
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: editing().title, valueUpdate: 'input'">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Priority:
      <select data-bind='options: priorityOptions, value: editing().priority'></select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: addProject, enable: editing().title">Add Project</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>Projects:</div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: projects">
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
      (<span data-bind="text: priority"></span>)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, this works quite well. I had to make some alterations in my HTML, specifically that the text of the <li> elements within my foreach <ul> (shown in the fiddle but not the post as I thought it wasn't relevant) had to be changed from 'title' to 'title()'. Otherwise this is quite effective. 
And I apologize for the weirdness with var np, I just didn't clean up my code before I posted. Thanks for your help.