# How to use "with" binding in Knockout JS with nested View Models?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am trying to write a template to fill a form for multiple persons. I do not want to go in for "foreach" binding or template. I am just trying to save all the data in the simple form with 5 inputs using a button that will add the person to the observableArray and clear the form for the next person.

I have pasted my entire code below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Knockouts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="rootDiv">
        <ul data-bind="with: Person">
            <li data-bind="event: { click: $data.setupPersonTypeForm.bind($data, 'Member') }">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="home">
                    <span class="radio-label">Member</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-bind="event: { click: $data.setupPersonTypeForm.bind($data, 'Guest') }">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="messages">
                    <span class="radio-label">Guest</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-bind="event: { click: $data.setupPersonTypeForm.bind($data, 'Employee') }">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="profile">
                    <span class="radio-label">Employee</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            Person Name:
            <input type="text" data-bind="text: PersonName" /><br />
            Person Age:
            <input type="text" data-bind="text: PersonAge" /><br />
            Person Type:
            <input type="text" data-bind="text: PersonType" /><br />
            Person Country:
            <input type="text" data-bind="text: PersonCountry" /><br />
            Person NetWorth:
            <input type="text" data-bind="text: PersonNetWorth" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script src="knockout-3.4.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (e) {

            var element = document.getElementById("rootDiv");
            ko.applyBindings(rootVM, element);

            var RootVM = function (data) {
                var self = this;

                self.Id = ko.observable();
                self.Name = ko.observable();
                self.Location = ko.observable();
                self.TypeId = ko.observable();
                self.Age = ko.observable();

                self.Person = ko.observableArray([new PersonVM()]);
            }
            var rootVM = new RootVM();


            var PersonVM = function (data) {
                var self = this;

                self.Id = ko.observable();
                self.PersonName = ko.observable();
                self.PersonType = ko.observable();
                self.PersonAge = ko.observable();
                self.PersonCountry = ko.observable();
                self.PersonNetWorth = ko.observable();

                self.PersonTypeIdPlaceholder = ko.observable();
                self.ShowEmployeeTitleField = ko.observable(false);

                self.setupPersonTypeForm = function (personType) {

                    self.ShowEmployeeTitleField(false);

                    switch (personType) {

                        case "Member":
                            self.PersonTypeIdPlaceholder("Member ID");
                            break;
                        case "Guest":
                            self.PersonTypeIdPlaceholder("Guest ID");
                            break;
                        case "Employee":
                            self.PersonTypeIdPlaceholder("Employee ID");
                            self.ShowEmployeeTitleField(true);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                self.setupPersonTypeForm('Member');

                self.Property = ko.observableArray([new PropertyVM()]);
            }

            var PropertyVM = function (data) {
                var self = this;

                self.Id = ko.observable();
                self.PropertyPlace = ko.observable();
                self.PropertySize = ko.observable();
                self.PropertyName = ko.observable();
                self.PropertyAge = ko.observable();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error:

> knockout-3.4.0.js:72 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process
>   binding "with: function (){return Person }" Message: Person is not
>   defined

Where am i going wrong here?

Any help would be appreciated!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this line:

```
ko.applyBindings(rootVM, element);
```

...`rootVM` is `undefined`, you haven't assigned it any value yet. You want to move that to **after** your

```
var rootVM = new RootVM();
```

...which in turn needs to be **after** the

```
var PersonVM = function (data) { ... };
```

...since it uses `PersonVM`.

Only *declarations* are hoisted, not assignments. When you have:

```
(function() {
    console.log(foo);

    var foo = 42;
})();
```

...you see `undefined`, not 42, because that code is interpreted as:

```
(function() {
    var foo = undefined;

    console.log(foo);

    foo = 42;
})();
```

That's happening all through your code.

There are at least a couple of other issues as well:

1. You're using `Person` as though it were a single thing, but you're defining it as an array of things. Once you fix the issue above, you have the issue that the `click` event can't be bound because arrays don't have a `setupPersonTypeForm` method (your `Person` does, not the array it's inside).
2. You're using properties below the list that only exist on `Person`, but only using the `with: Person` on the list.

If your goal is to have a list of people, and to be able to add/edit people on that list with a form, [my answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36138887/157247) shows how to do something nearly identical, just with "projects" rather than "people".

Here's the simple example in that answer duplicated for context:

```js
function Project(title, priority) {
  this.title = ko.observable(title || "");
  this.priority = ko.observable(priority || "Medium");
}


function ProjectViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.priorityOptions = ko.observableArray(["High", "Medium", "Low"]);
  this.projects = ko.observableArray();
  this.editing = ko.observable(new Project());
  this.addProject = function() {
    this.projects.push(this.editing());
    this.editing(new Project());
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ProjectViewModel(), document.body);
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Title:
      <input type="text" data-bind="value: editing().title, valueUpdate: 'input'">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Priority:
      <select data-bind='options: priorityOptions, value: editing().priority'></select>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: addProject, enable: editing().title">Add Project</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>Projects:</div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: projects">
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
      (<span data-bind="text: priority"></span>)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> 1. If we had some sub-category for each Project, and i would like to add several of the sub-category items within each specific project. In which viewmodel do you place the addSubCategory function. How do you keep track of each grandchild item?

You just repeat the same structure, nested. For instance, we can readily add a list of "tasks" in our "project"s.

> 2. Why can't we use the "with" binding? Is there a limitation in knockout for that?

You can if you like. I didn't in the original example because I only had two fields on a project, but you could put `data-bind="with: editing"` in the above to wrap those in a `with` instead.

Here's an example with tasks and using `with` bindings (I've changed `editing` from the above to `editProject` since now we also have `editTask`):

```js
function Task(label, difficulty) {
  this.label = ko.observable(label);
  this.difficulty = ko.observable(difficulty || "Normal");
}

function Project(title, priority) {
  this.title = ko.observable(title || "");
  this.priority = ko.observable(priority || "Medium");
  this.tasks = ko.observableArray();
  this.editTask = ko.observable(new Task());
  this.addTask = function() {
    this.tasks.push(this.editTask());
    this.editTask(new Task());
  };
}


function ProjectViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  this.priorityOptions = ko.observableArray(["High", "Medium", "Low"]);
  this.difficultyOptions = ko.observableArray(["Hard", "Normal", "Easy"]);
  this.projects = ko.observableArray();
  this.editProject = ko.observable(new Project());
  this.addProject = function() {
    this.projects.push(this.editProject());
    this.editProject(new Project());
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new ProjectViewModel(), document.body);
```

```css
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- Added a new div with a 'with' binding -->
  <div data-bind="with: editProject">
    <div>
      <label>
        Title:
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: title, valueUpdate: 'input'">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Priority:
        <select data-bind='options: $parent.priorityOptions, value: priority'></select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 3em">
      Tasks for this project:
      <div style="padding-left: 2em">
        New task:
        <div data-bind="with: editTask">
          <div>
            <label>
              Difficulty:
              <select data-bind='options: $root.difficultyOptions, value: difficulty'></select>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>
              Label:
              <input type="text" data-bind="value: label, valueUpdate: 'input'">
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: addTask, enable: editTask().label">Add Task</button>
      </div>
      <div data-bind="foreach: tasks">
        <div>
          [<span data-bind="text: difficulty"></span>]
          <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: addProject, enable: editProject().title">Add Project</button>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div>Projects:</div>
  <div data-bind="foreach: projects">
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
      (<span data-bind="text: priority"></span>)
    </div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: tasks">
      <li>[<span data-bind="text: difficulty"></span>]: <span data-bind="text: label"></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As you suggested, I put: var PropertyVM first and then var PersonVM next and then var RootVM followed by the likes: var element = document.getElementById("rootDiv"); and ko.applyBindings(new RootVM(), element); - Yet the same error persists.

Comment: @zapper: See further notes at the bottom. There are several issues with that code. You'll need to debug them individually (which is not an activity suited to SO).

Comment: @zapper: I've also added a simple example of something which I suspect is nearly identical to what you're trying to do, with a link to an answer (of mine) explaining it.

Comment: thanks for your solution. But, in my problem, there is a collection within a collection. So, in your example, 

1. If we had some sub-category for each Project, and i would like to add several of the sub-category items within each specific project. In which viewmodel do you place the addSubCategory function. How do you keep track of each grandchild item?
2. Why can't we use the "with" binding? Is there a limitation in knockout for that?

Comment: @zapper: I've updated the answer. But usually, if you're asking "Why can't we do X, is it a limitation of Y?" where Y is a reasonably-well-thought-out tool, the answer is either "You can" or "You don't want to" rather than "Yes, it's a limitation."

Comment: That is awesome!. Thanks a lot!. Totally appreciate it!.