# Knockout JS - How to initialize a complex object as observable?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a ViewModel and have an observable property that will have a complex object after an edit link is clicked. This is a basic example of managing a set of Groups. User can click on the 'edit' link and I want to capture that Group in SelectedGroup property.

But I'm not sure how should I initialize the SelectedGroup and make every peoperty in this object as observable to begin with.

```
function ManageGroupsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Groups = ko.observableArray();
    self.IsLoading = ko.observable(false);
    self.SelectedGroup = ko.observable();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you'd start out with `SelectedGroup` being `null`:

```
self.SelectedGroup = ko.observable(null);
```

...and then when you're ready to edit a group, just set it to a new instance; if that instance needs observable properties, you create them just like you did for `ManageGroupsViewModel`:

```
function GroupVM() {
    this.name = ko.observable("");
    this.members = ko.observableArray();
}
```

and

```
// Start editing a group
yourGroupsViewModel.SelectedGroup(new GroupVM());
```

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36481585/157247) of mine has a fairly thorough example of doing this.